# cordova inappbrowser iOS issues

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working on an app for both android and iOS that will be opening external links. I am currently using cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 to open my links and it is working perfectly in Android, but I seem to be running into the same problem that many other people have. In iOS, I do not get a toolbar to appear and thus am stuck as I cannot click on the "done" button (or back/forward buttons for that matter.) I have built the app using both phonegap build online and through the command line tools, with the same behavior in each instance. It does not work in either an emulated environment or a native device environment. I have been searching online and this seems to be an extremely common problem, but none of the proposed solutions have worked over the past 2 days and ~15 hours of testing (for just a stupid little link!)  I would like to remain in-app, but would not be opposed to going to safari if that is the only solution. My relevant code and versions:
Phonegap cli-5.1.1 (iOS 3.8/Android 4.02)
Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1

config.xml relevent code:

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</plugins>

<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

index.html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // Global InAppBrowser reference
         var iabRef = null;
        function iabLoadStart(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }
        function iabLoadStop(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }
        function iabClose(event) {
             alert(event.type);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
             iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }
        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
             alert('Device is ready!');
             //iabRef = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
             //iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
             //iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
             //iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }
        </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .centeredImage
        {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding:0px;
        }
        body
        {
        background: #000 !important;
        background-image:url(backgrounds/1080widephone.png) !important;
        background-size:cover !important;  
        }
        .ui-content{
        background: transparent !important;
        }
        .ui-page{
        background: transparent !important;
        }
        .ui-footer{
        background: transparent !important;
        }        
    </style>
</head>
```

Various links (all act as buttons):

```
window.open('url' ,'_blank')
```

(NOTE: This appears to open in the default WebView for iOS and the inappbrowser for Android)

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('url' ,'_blank', 'location=yes' , 'toolbar=yes', 'toolbarposition=top' , closebuttoncaption=Return'
```

(NOTE: Nothing happens when I use this in either iOS or Android builds. I based this syntax off of the [description](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser))

My kneejerk reaction is that the plugin isn't loading, but I don't see how that can be the case if it is clearly working in an android build but not an iOS build using exactly the same code on phonegap build. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm running around in circles here!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response but I’ve found one possible solution.

In my case, I was using ngCordova’s `$InAppBrowser` within the Ionic framework to open a file or url. To test this, I was using Xcode’s iPhone simulator as well as Ionic’s “Ionic View” app. Within both of these options, `$InAppBrowser` will NOT show a “Back” or “Done” button.

However, if you open your project’s `.xcodeproj` in Xcode and run your application on an actual iOS device, the InAppBrowser should work as expected.

I spent hours on this issue only to discover Ionic View restricts the `options` of $InAppBrowser. However, I’m still not 100% sure as to why this doesn’t work in the iOS emulator.

Note: I believe all of this applies even if you’re directly using Cordova and not ngCordova.

Answer (score 0):

The values for the options string in

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open
```

needs to be a single string of name=value pairs separated by ,

So try:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('url' ,'_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=Return');
```

Additionally you should make sure your application's links open with the IAB by hijacking them and opening them in the IAB and suppressing the default event... for example with JQuery to hijack all the links in a div with id "infoExternalContent" and open them in the IAB with some options set for iOS only (using Cordova device platform to detect platform):

```
$('#infoExternalContent').find('a').each(
    function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var iabOptions = (device.platform === 'iOS' ? 'location=no,enableViewportScale=yes,transitionstyle=fliphorizontal' : '');

        if (href.indexOf('http') === 0) {
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                cordova.InAppBrowser.open(''.concat(this.href), '_blank', iabOptions);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that did not work. I used phonegap build to compile both Android and iOS apps with the new code. It worked perfectly in my Android app, but the link didn't work at all in iOS (clicking on the button does nothing.) 
I suspect the plugin is not installing on iOS, but have no way to verify. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use phonegap build, but I can't imagine that it wants all of this loaded ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
```

cordova.js is loaded twice, along with phonegap.js. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

If you uncomment

```
 iabRef = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

What happens?

I would also try

```
 cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

If neither of those open a window to apache, I would readd the plugin.

Comment: Nothing happens in either case. I've removed and re-added the plugin several times to no avail. Is there some sort of versioning error with the plugins and iOS 9? Would it be worth the effort to try and use a different plugin like childbrowser?